# How to have all files use tabs as indentation?

Tags: javascript, angular, indentation

I'm using Angular and would like to use tab indentation (size 4), rather than the 2-space indentation at default. However, there seems to be no effective way of doing this, other than manually using the following method EVERY time I generate a new file.

[bottom right of VSCode] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDrSJ.png

[commands] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcMlH.png

Comment: We can't tell you how to configure your unspecified editor and unspecified code formatting plug ins.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JavaScript or Angular. Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use prettier. https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/498b012fbd-run-prettier-on-all-javascript-files-in-a-dir

You just need to set the options to use 4 spaces and then run it on all your files.